# Is there any regression model for giving me a mathematical equation according to the dataset values?

Tags: python, math, non-linear-regression

I am working on a dataset in which there are three columns: x, y and z, as shown in the picture below.

The x and y are independent variables in a mathematical equation, and the z is the product of some mathematical operations between x and y and some coefficients. Now, I would like to know if there is any regression model which is able to give the mathematical equation. An equation something like:

z = 4x^2 + 67xy - 3y

[My dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4DBm.png)

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: There's [functions - Find formula from values - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11502/find-formula-from-values) but... (on the other hand, why would you want to do that?)

Comment: Actually, I want to do that to help my friend's thesis which studies Mechanical Engineering, and he needs to perform complex computations. @user202729